# All default 'Apple' icons disappeared on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, ios

I restarted my iPhone 7 today and all stock Apple apps have disappeared like Safari and Settings.  If I search for them they do not appear either.

I tried connecting my phone to iTunes and backing up and then doing a restore. But when I do this it tells me to turn off Find My iPhone.. Which I cannot do without the Settings app.

My phone is up to date with is 10.

How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know the AppleID and password for the device, you can restore without needing to get to the settings app:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

This option is needed for service and if you sell a device and forget to unlock it before it leaves your possession. When multiple apps are broken, a restore is almost always the fix and something you should try once you back up the device as best you can before the erase.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove some of the default Apple apps and then "reinstall" them by going to the app store. There will be a download for the missing app which will re-activate it. But Settings is not one of the ones that you can remove.

I think that I would (after verifying you have a recent backup of the phone) restore the iPhone to [factory default](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252). Basically connect the phone to your computer, open iTunes, click on the phone icon at the top of the window and then click the "Restore iPhone" button (top right).

That link has more details and what to do under other circumstances. One of those procedures should do it.